# how to use PHP function to get ranks for multiple columns in a table more efficent

Tags: php, mysql, function, multiple-columns, rank

I am trying to get single rank for a user for each stat "column" in the table. I am trying to do this as more efficiently because i know you can.

So I have a table called userstats. in that table i have 3 columns user_id, stat_1, stat_2, and stat_3. I want to me able to get the rank for each stat for the associated user_id. with my current code below i would have to duplicate the code 3x and change the column names to get my result. please look at the examples below. Thanks!

this is how i currently get the rank for the users

> $rankstat1 = getUserRank($userid);

```
<code>
function getUserRank($userid){

   $sql     =  "SELECT * FROM ".DB_USERSTATS." ORDER BY stat_1 DESC";
   $result =  mysql_query($sql);
   $rows  =  '';

   $data = array();
   if (!empty($result))
        $rows      =  mysql_num_rows($result);
   else
        $rows      =  '';

    if (!empty($rows)){
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $data[]   = $rows;
        }
    }

   $rank = 1;
   foreach($data as $item){
       if ($item['user_id'] == $userid){
           return $rank;
       }
       ++$rank;
   }
   return 1;
}
</code>
```

I believe there is a way for me to get what i need with something like this but i cant get it to work.

> $rankstat1 = getUserRank($userid, 'stat_1'); $rankstat2 =
>   getUserRank($userid, 'stat_2'); $rankstat3 = getUserRank($userid,
>   'stat_3');

Comment: The premise here is wrong.  You don't want to query the db to get each rank (i.e.  you don't want to call your getUserRank function 3 times for every user).  Call it once, and then parse the result to get the particular stat you want.  Also, avoid SELECT *.  Specify the column names you want in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the stat ranks using one query without doing all the PHP looping and checking.

I have used PDO in this example because the value of the `$userid` variable needs to be used in the query, and the deprecated `mysql` database extension does not support prepared statements, which should be used to reduce the risk of SQL injection.

The function could be adapted to use the same query with `mysqli`, or even `mysql` if you must use it.

```
function getUserRanks($userid, $pdo) {
    $sql = "SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT s1.user_id) + 1 AS stat_1_rank, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT s2.user_id) + 1 AS stat_2_rank, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT s3.user_id) + 1 AS stat_3_rank
    FROM user_stats f
        LEFT JOIN user_stats s1 ON f.stat_1 < s1.stat_1
        LEFT JOIN user_stats s2 ON f.stat_2 < s2.stat_2
        LEFT JOIN user_stats s3 ON f.stat_3 < s3.stat_3
    WHERE f.user_id = ?"

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $ranks = $stmt->fetchObject();
    return $ranks;
}
```

This should return an object with properties containing the ranks of the given user for each stat. An example of using this function:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
$ranks = getUserRanks(3, $pdo);      // get the stat ranks for user 3
echo $ranks->stat_2_rank;            // show user 3's rank for stat 2
```

Comment: i believe ";" is missing at the end of WHERE f.user_id = ?" | but do i put the users id where the "?" is what do i place inplace of the question mark? im not getting anything to be returned with this one error "Trying to get property of non-object Line: 77"

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql     =  "SELECT user_id, stat_1, stat_2, stat_3 FROM ".DB_USERSTATS." ORDER BY stat_1 DESC";
```

Also, unless there is a reason you need ALL users results, limit your query with a WHERE clause so you're only getting the results you actually need.

Assuming you limit your sql query to just one user, this will get that user's stats.

```
foreach($data as $item){
   $stat_1 = $item['stat_1'];
   $stat_2 = $item['stat_2'];
   $stat_3 = $item['stat_3'];
}
```

If you get more than one user's stats with your sql query, consider passing your $data array back to the calling function and loop through the array to match the users stats to particular user id's.

Comment: Are you able to run the sql in phpmyadmin or whatever mysql query tool you use?